# SQL Server complete log file view

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-files

I made a backup maintenance plan in SQL server 2008. When I run the maintenance plan it fails with an error. When I go to the SQL protocol viewer I can look at the log which has been generated. But sometimes the log is shortened in form of unfinished sentences with "..." at the end.

I can see the error message but as mentioned above the error gets shortened in a form that I can't  understand the message. Is it somehow possible to bypass this shortening of errors and get the complete error message?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

- Go to the properties of the Job (for that Maintenance Plan)
- Steps --> Edit
- Click Advanced
- Give the path of the outputfile (can be anything) under "Output File"
- Click Ok to Save the job

From the next run of the job, you will be able to get the complete job log.